# Why does Kubotek KeyCreator 2011 crash when loading a workspace in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I'm having an issue getting KeyCreator 2011 to work with Windows 10. This software works fine in Windows 7 on the same PC, but after updating the OS, the program will crash when attempting to load a workspace. I have tried a clean format and reinstall of Windows and can confirm that my drivers and Windows itself are up to date.

I have tried this on several PCs with both Intel and AMD CPUs as well as NVIDIA and AMD graphics. It appears to be an issue specifically with Windows 10.

I have tried setting the program for Windows 7 Compatibility Mode and running as Administrator but this did not provide any change improvement.

The crash is reported in Event Viewer but I don't see anything useful from the report.

Does anyone know of a workaround to fix this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check the Event Viewer for information about the crash.

Comment: Have you tried setting its compatibility to Win 7 [or earlier]?

Comment: @Tetsujin I've tried this, yes.

Comment: @harrymc I checked Event Viewer but I didn't see anything useful from the output.

Comment: Please add all pertinent information to your question. It saves duplication of effort.

Comment: There was a 10.5 release, but I doubt the company has even looked at whether a 10-year-old version will still run on a modern OS.

Comment: I also found reference to a 10.5 release but was unable to locate this update. I only have the original install media for 10.0.2.

Comment: It's not entirely surprising that a "2011" release does not work on the latest operating systems. Windows 8, 8.1 and Window 10 have all brought significant changes since 2011. You might have to simply bite the bullet and upgrade: https://www.kubotek3d.com/products/keycreator

Comment: From https://help.kubotek3d.com/keycreator?id=&version=V15.0 there are a lot more up to date versions.

Answer (score 0):

The exception code `0xc0000374` indicates a heap corruption, which
indicates some incompatibility of the program with Windows 10 DLLs.

There is no point in debugging the crash, since you do not control
its code and cannot modify anything.

My advice would be to create a virtual machine with Windows 7 and
install there this product and all its dependencies.
This has a good chance of working.

A later version of the product will work better on Windows 10,
but will require payment.